# Is sanitize_title enough to generate post slugs?

Tags: seo, slug, sanitization

I want to generate slug for some strings without going through WordPress slug generation flow. Therefore, I want to know which functions it calls to get a neat slug. I tried sanitize_title() but it leaves %c2 %a0 in result.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are almost there. The function you need is [sanitize_title_with_dashes( $title )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes)

Comment: While this definitely appears correct, I'm a little unclear what sanitize_title_with_dashes seems to do differently to sanitize_title. sanitize_title is also adding dashes where whitespace is...

Comment: If you check the WordPress Codex for [sanitize_title_with_dashes( $title )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title_with_dashes), you will see the note **'it does not replace special accented characters'** which means characters like `èäç` etc. will stay in place with this function.

Comment: Please note that `sanitize_title_with_dashes` as well as `sanitize_title` leave some special characters that may break some systems. I you want a more universal approach in reducing strings take a look at `sanitize_html_class`

Answer (score 11):

`sanitize_title()` seems to be the only one you need.

In wp-includes/default-filters.php line 211 you will find:

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_title', 'sanitize_title_with_dashes', 10, 3);
```

This means that calling `sanitize_title()` will first remove all the special characters, then apply the `sanitize_title` filter, thus calling `sanitize_title_with_dashes()`

As @JHoffmann pointed out, simply calling `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` will not remove special characters.

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

Well, there is already an answer, but I wanted to expand it a bit, so here are my findings:

If we have a look in `wp_insert_post()` we see, the `$post_name` is sanitized using `wp_sanitize_title()` ( see [`wp-includes/post.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/4.7/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3090))

In the function `sanitize_title()` we have a filter `sanitize_title`. This is interesting, since in the default filters `sanitize_title_with_dashes()` is hooked into this filter (see [`wp-includes/default-filters.php`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/4.7/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L205)).

```
<?php
echo sanitize_title( 'Â+ÄÖßáèäç' ) // aaeoessaeaec
?>
```

> I tried sanitize_title() but it leaves %c2 %a0 in result.

This sounds strange. It would be great to know the input value, but following `wp_insert_post()` `sanitize_title()` seems to be enough.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to websupporter's great [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/251921/1839) I found the below:

Depending on your usage it will depend what you need.

`sanitize_title()` as it says:

> accents are removed (accented characters are replaced with non-accented equivalents)

...and `sanitize_title_with_dashes` says:

> Note that it **does not replace special accented characters**

So, with this *example* string: ``` Â+Ä Ö %%% ßá %20 oo %pp + -_^^#@!**()=[]|\/\'"<>?``~ èäç ```

`sanitize_title()` result:

> aa-o-sa-%20-oo-pp-_-eac

As you can see it has *replaced* accented characters with their non-accented equivalents **and** it has removed all other non-alphanumeric characters apart from the `%` which is followed by a number, but you will see it was removed when it was followed by a letter; perhaps this is because it perceives it as [already encoded](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/url-encoding). This is enforced when you try inserting `%c3` into your string, it doesn't strip it as `%c3` is a valid encoding sequence.

`sanitize_title_with_dashes` result:

> %c3%a2%c3%a4-%c3%b6-%c3%9f%c3%a1-%20-oo-pp-_-%c3%a8%c3%a4%c3%a7

So as you can see it hasn't removed the accented characters, but encoded them.

Now let's look at a string with *no* accented characters to see how they both behave...

**Example String:** ``` %%% building %20 oo %pp + -_^^#@!**()=[]|\/\'"<>?``~' ```

`sanitize_title()` result:

> building-%20-oo-pp-_

`sanitize_title_with_dashes` result:

> building-%20-oo-pp-_

So as you can see they are *exactly* the same. So it appears the only difference in them is that one *encodes* accented charters whilst the other *replaces* them.